# Redirect domain names on the same hosting

Tags: domain, name

I have four domain names, but I will have only one site. All the domains will point to this one site. I have read that Google will treat this as duplicate content, and rate that as a bad practice or a black hat move to trick the SEO.

I could do the .htaccess 301 trick, but will this work with all the domains pointing to the same DNS?

I am sure I am not the only one out there with more than one domain!

Answer (score 1):

If you point the domain name to the domain name you want to use it won't be a problem.

For example, redirect `www.example.net` to `www.example.com`.

The search engines will typically leave you alone on that.

---

Another (more common issue) is when someone has `example.com` and `www.example.com` pointing to the same place.  The solution for that would be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You should be able to take the above example and modify it to fit your needs.